# Make a dropdown type Combobox behave like an Edit control

Tags: windows, winapi, combobox, user32

I'm about to replace a standard edit control with a dropdown type combo box. So basically that combobox bahaves like exactly like an edit control.

Everything works fine so far but there is just one notable difference:

- When you click on the edit control containing already some text and that doesn't have the focus, the cursor is simply positioned where you click.
- But when you click on a the combo box containing already some text and that doesn't have the focus, the whole text is selected.

This depicts the situation what happens when you click on either the combobox or the edit control where the red arrow points when neither has the focus:

[image]

Is there a way to  make the combo box behave like an edit control?

Comment: Possibly by sub-classing and modifying what `WM_GETDLGCODE` returns (as described [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20031114-00/?p=41823)) although I'm not exactly sure for a combo. Maybe you'd have to subclass the edit control within the combo.

Comment: @JonathanPotter that looks promising, thanks

Comment: @Jabberwocky Removing the
DLGC_HASSETSEL flag doesn't work for Combobox for me. Does it work for you?

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT I haven't tried yet as this is not a major problem for me right now. How did did you use `DLGC_HASSETSEL`? Did you subclass the combo box or the combo box's edit control?

Comment: @Jabberwocky I subclass the edit control of the combobox like this:`comboEditHdl = FindWindowEx(cmbHdl, NULL, L"Edit", NULL);  SetWindowSubclass(comboEditHdl,RemoveHasSetSelSubclassProc, 0, 0);` And in subclass procedure: `case WM_GETDLGCODE:
   return DefSubclassProc(hwnd, uiMsg, wParam, lParam)
   & ~DLGC_HASSETSEL;`

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT are you sure `FindWindowEx` is the right thing to do? Who knows what it _actually_ finds. I'd rather use  [GetComboBoxInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getcomboboxinfo).  That is: `COMBOBOXINFO cbi = {sizeof(COMBOBOXINFO)};
GetComboBoxInfo(cmbHdl, &cbi));
comboEditHdl = cbi.hwndItem);`

Comment: @Jabberwocky Great suggestion! Thanks. I double check the found edit window handle and made sure it is the right one. Just test using `GetComboBoxInfo` unfortunately, it doesn't work either.

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT OK, thanks. I'll live with that for the moment. If ever I get it to work in the future, I'll let you know and I'll post an answer here.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Does my solution works for you?

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT not yet tried, but it looks good. I'll let you know. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

One of solution to prevent the whole text selected is via subclass a Combo Box and setting focus to its edit control when the mouse left button click on it at first time. Code as below:

**Subclass procedure:**

```
LRESULT CALLBACK EditSubClassProc(HWND hWnd,
    UINT uMsg,
    WPARAM wParam,
    LPARAM lParam,
    UINT_PTR uIdSubclass,
    DWORD_PTR dwRefData
    )
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
    case WM_DESTROY:
    {
        RemoveWindowSubclass(hWnd, EditSubClassProc, 0);
        return DefSubclassProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
    {
        if (GetFocus() != hWnd)
        {
            SetFocus(hWnd);
        }
        return DefSubclassProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    default:
        return DefSubclassProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    }
}
```

**Find edit control window of Combo Box and install the subclass callback:**

```
   //  Get the edit window handle to combo box. 
   HWND comboEditHdl = NULL;
   COMBOBOXINFO info = { 0 };
   info.cbSize = sizeof(COMBOBOXINFO);

   if (!GetComboBoxInfo(hwndCombo1, &info))
       return 0;

   comboEditHdl = info.hwndItem;

   if (comboEditHdl)
   {
       SetWindowSubclass(comboEditHdl, EditSubClassProc, 0, NULL);
   }
```