# How to unselect the text in a Combobox with dropdown style?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, combobox, user32

In Windows C API I have a combobox with dropdown style. I set a text in the edit control of the combo box during the dialog initialization. I want the text to be shown unselected.

I send the following messages:

```
SendDlgItemMessage(hDlg, IDC_EDIT_FIND, CB_SETCURSEL,0,0);
SendDlgItemMessage(hDlg, IDC_EDIT_FIND, CB_SETEDITSEL,0,MAKELPARAM(-1,0));
```

but the text is not unselected. The documentation says about `CB_SETEDITSEL`:

> lParam
>
> *[in] The low-order word of lParam specifies the starting position. If the low-order word is –1, the selection, if any, is removed.*
>
> *The high-order word of lParam specifies the ending position. If the high-order word is –1, all text from the starting position to the last character in the edit control is selected.*

And:

> If the message succeeds, the return value is TRUE. If the message is sent to a combo box *with the CBS_DROPDOWNLIST style, it is CB_ERR.*

When I send the message, the result is 1 (TRUE) but the text in the edit control is not unselected

How can I unselect the text of the combobox edit control?

Comment: Have you tried sending a [`CB_GETEDITSEL`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/cb-geteditsel) to see if the start/end positions have changed? If they have, then maybe just a `RedrawWindow()` call?

Comment: @AdrianMole, working on your suggestion. After `CB_SETCURSEL`, `CB_GETEDITSEL` reports 0,0. After `CB_SETEDITSEL` 5,7, `CB_GETEDITSEL` reports 5,7; however, the text is just selected (blue) and pressing a key erases the text so it is selected. Todo: redraw, but I doubt it.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie This reminds me [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60389510/make-a-dropdown-type-combobox-behave-like-an-edit-control) I've asked some time ago. It's not quite the same, but the issue is pretty similar. I haven't found a solution though and I gave up. Maybe the comments and the answer (not working for me) there may help.

Comment: @Jabberwocky, I found a solution. You could use it too in your situation. Before loosing the focus remember the cursor position, then when the focus is set again to your control, unselect (see my solution) and place the cursor at its old position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it: After `WM_INITDIALOG`, Windows sets the focus to the control designated as the first control in the dialog definition, which happened to be the combo box. This caused the focus to be set to the combo box and, no matter how much we have reset it in the `WM_INITDIALOG`, the combo text is selected again by the SetFocus.

The solution is to "ignore" this by resetting the selection.

The following is my solution. I use a semaphore to prevent processing of SetFocus messages for the control during the processing of the `WM_INITDIALOG` message:

```
BOOL CALLBACK DlgProcExample (HWND hDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    static int semaIgnore;

    switch (message)
    {
        case WM_INITDIALOG:
            semaIgnore=TRUE;
                SendDlgItemMessage(hDlg, IDC_COMBO, CB_RESETCONTENT, 0, 0);
                SendDlgItemMessage(hDlg, IDC_COMBO, CB_ADDSTRING,0, (LPARAM)"Hello World");
                SendDlgItemMessage(hDlg, IDC_COMBO, CB_SETCURSEL,0,0);
            semaIgnore= FALSE;
            return (TRUE);

       case WM_COMMAND:
            switch (LOWORD(wParam))
            {
                case IDC_COMBO:
                    if (semaIgnore) break;
                    switch (HIWORD(wParam)) {
                    case CBN_SETFOCUS:
                        SendDlgItemMessage(hDlg, IDC_COMBO, CB_SETEDITSEL,0,MAKELPARAM(-1,99));
                        break;
                    }
                    break;
            }
            break;
        //...
```

Comment: Another way you could do it is to sub-class the control to handle `WM_GETDLGCODE` and remove the `DLGC_HASSETSEL` flag from the standard return value.

Comment: I am glad you have got your solution and thanks for your sharing, I would appreciate it if you mark them as answer and this will be beneficial to other community.